# Java annotation class parameter

Tags: java, annotations

Can you please show me an example where one would create parameter in annotation with `Class` type? I couldn't find where it would be reasonable.

For example I have created annotation for user inputs and it has a validator that validates for emails, phone numbers. So I would create something like this:

```
@interface FormField{
Class<? extends IValidator> validator() default EmptyValidator.class;
}
```

Though I could do it, I have to go through using reflections to create instance, etc.

I think the more intuitive would be to create enum something like

```
public enum ValidationCriteria {
FREE_TEXT, EMAIL, PHONE
}
```

and annotation now would be

```
@interface FormField{
ValidationCriteria validator() default ValidationCriteria.FREE_TEXT;
}
```

Than I could create factory with `Hashmap<ValidationCriteria, Validator>` and get the desired validator. It is way more intuitive to me and I don't see why I would ever use `Class` `type`. 
Could you explain me why and where?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little with a sample code?

Comment: I added code about my frustration

Comment: Still not so clear. But seems like you are trying to implement your own Bean Validation, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20723594/738746) for example.

Comment: I just want to see some example where class type parameter is applicable and how it is used

Comment: If you don't control all the different possible values of your type, or if there's another reason you can't use an enum.